# Why does Ito Chain Rule make no sense?

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus, finance

$$dY\Big(X(t)\Big) = \bigg(\frac{d}{dt}Y + \frac{d}{dX}Y  \cdot \mu(t) + \frac{d^{2}}{dX^{2}}Y \cdot \frac{1}{2}\sigma^{2}(t)\bigg) \cdot dt +  \Big(\frac{d}{dX}Y \cdot \sigma(t)\Big) \cdot dW$$

Logically these two should cancel out

$$\require{cancel} \cancel{dY\Big(X(t)\Big)} = \bigg(\cancel{\frac{d}{dt}Y} + \frac{d}{dX}Y  \cdot \mu(t) + \frac{d^{2}}{dX^{2}}Y \cdot \frac{1}{2}\sigma^{2}(t)\bigg) \cdot dt +  \Big(\frac{d}{dX}Y \cdot \sigma(t)\Big) \cdot dW$$

But they do not. Moreseo they are treated differently -- $dY\Big(X(t)\Big)$ as a function and $\frac{d}{dt}Y \cdot dt$ as a constant, which makes no sense to me.

Comment: Why would they cancel out? On the left you have a stochastic differential, on the right you don't.

Answer (score 1):

Do we assume $dX_t = X_t(\mu dt + \sigma dW_t)$ or some such? At any rate, Ito's lemma implies
$$ dY(X_t) = Y'(X_t)dX_t + \frac{1}{2}Y''(X_t)d\langle X \rangle _t $$

You would cancel out $dY(X_t)$ and $Y'dt$ - they're not the same thing (one is a stochastic differential, the other is not).

For this to make sense, $Y$ is just some (at least) twice continuously differentiable map $Y:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$. It makes no sense to distinguish between $\frac{d}{dt}Y$ and $\frac{d}{dX}Y$.

If you were working with a parametrised version of Ito's lemma, we could have $Y=Y(x,t)$ and we'd have to bring in partial derivatives.

Comment: So to make it less confusing would it probably make more sense to use the notation: 
$$dY\Big(X(t)\Big) = \bigg(\frac{d}{dt}y + \frac{d}{dx}y  \cdot \mu(t) + \frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}y \cdot \frac{1}{2}\sigma^{2}(t)\bigg) \cdot dt +  \Big(\frac{d}{dx}y \cdot \sigma(t)\Big) \cdot dW$$ where $Y$ is a random function and $y$ is a deterministic one?

Comment: @A.L.Verminburger $Y$ is a single variable function, take the derivatives and evaluate them at $X_t$.